# Getting buildroot to put Grub2 in target filesystem

Tags: buildroot

I am making two buildroot projects.
one is used to build a bootable CD/USB/VM image.
the other build an image to be installed from the CD.

the flow is:

1. CD boots
2. initramfs starts
3. find hard disk
4. partition and format hard disk
5. install rootfs image onto hard disk
6. install grub onto hard disk

I have steps 1-5 working.

for step 6, I have tried to hack the grub2.mk file to install the grub files into the target filesystem, but have not been successful.

has anyone else managed to create an installer disk image from buildroot that can install onto a target system using grub2?

Comment: When grub2 was introduced in Buildroot, that feature was left out because it was complicated and the people contributing grub2 didn't need it. So if you do manage to get it working, please contribute patches to the Buildroot mailing list.

Comment: thanks for the info. I've posted this message on the buildroot mailing list as well, just in case someone has any pointers.

Comment: Andy, am currently trying to create installer image and struck.. could you help Sharing your instructions/insight and it will be much helpful.